# Js changes are not reflecting in the browser unless we redeploy the war file

Tags: javascript, java, tomcat, intellij-idea, spring-boot

I have developed a Spring Boot web application using IntelliJ. For every Js and html change I have to redeploy the war file in order to get the changes reflected on the browser. Is there any way to get the changes reflected on fly without redeploying?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement real time caching like nginx. create seperate project for css and ui related changes and link to assets folder of nginx. then you have to start that nginx server. so when u do changes in files, no need to restart server again and again. 
For more info https://www.nginx.com/blog/scaling-web-applications-nginx-part-ii-caching-monitoring/#caching

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to auto update browser code is to use [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) with [watch](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch) and [livereload](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-livereload). When you save changes to a file it will automatically be pushed to the browser. There's no need for browser plugins.

The following [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/eeJwKpTd12nU1Qug56M5) demonstrates a most basic usage. Drop the files into any directory, and run

```
npm install -g grunt-cli
npm install
grunt serve
```

It will start a webserver (connect) that serves index.html. Any changes done to index.html will automatically be sent to the browser. Connect is also configured to relay any requests to `/api/` to another HTTP-server (typically your local Jetty instance).

I included a typical configuration where you'll place JavaScript under `app/scripts`, CSS under `app/styles` and images under `app/images`. Updates to any of these will also be pushed to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a springboot version >= 1.3 you can use spring-boot-devtools module which includes an embedded liveReload server. From there all you'll need is a browser that supports the liveReload extention.

Maven POM

```
<dependencies>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
 </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
}
```